# Starting a script with a keypress without an X server

Tags: shortcut-keys, upstart

I am looking for a way to bind any sequence of keys to an action that will run a script. I need to accomplish this on a Ubuntu 12.10 server which does not have X. I have looked into Upstart however I am unable to find an event that satisfies my needs.